# Silverlight Toolkit Pie Chart Add Labels

Tags: silverlight, pie-chart, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have been working with Silverlight for some time now but this is my first experience with the charting capability provided by the silverlight toolkit. Basically I am trying to create a pie chart that contains labels for each slice of the pie. The labels can be inside the pie piece itself or outside it makes very little difference to me. My data set is very simple. I have a Result class that contains 2 properties, a name and a count and I am using that as the source for the pie chart.

I have tried to google this but most of the results I get pertain to telerik or other 3rd party controls.

Can someone please share there wisdom on how to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/pie-chart-in-silverlight/ - it should give you a start

Comment: @ChrisF yes that was the tutorial I used to get started with charting but unfortunately it does not mention anything about labeling the pie slices.

Comment: We use Infragistics controls here so I'm not familiar with the Toolkit variant, but doesn't the Intellisense throw up anything when you start to type `Label`? I'd look for something like `LabelPosition` on the series definition.

Comment: @ChrisF That's the thing there is no Label property at all. I don't know what to do or how to set it but feel like there must be a way to do it